# How to supply function arguments from a list?

Tags: ocaml

Assume I have a function `f` that takes `n` arguments of the same type `f: 'a * 'a * ... * 'a -> 'b`

Assume I have a list `l`of `n` `'a` elements,

Does the functor `call_function_with_list` exist? It would mean this: 
`call_function_with_list f l = f l[0] l[1] ... l[n-1]`

Observe that I am not interested in specifying a particular `call_function_with_list` for a fixed number `n` (which could be done quite simply) but I am interested in having a general `call_function_with_list` that works for all `n`

Comment: What would be a type of such function...?

Comment: @MarcinŁoś I was indeed wondering if such a type could be expressed at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't (without resorting to the dark magic of the `Obj` module, that is). Indeed, there are two issues. First OCaml's type system cannot represents something like `'a list -> ('a * 'a * ... * 'a)` where `...` actually depends on the length of the argument (you could do something like that in Coq for instance). Second, in OCaml an n-uple is not an iterated version of a pair, i.e. a value of type `'a * 'a * 'a` is neither a value of type `'a * ('a * 'a)` nor of type `('a * ('a * 'a))`, so that you cannot build your nuple step by step from the elements of the list.

```
# let x = (1,2,3);;
val x : int * int * int = (1, 2, 3)
# let y = (1,(2,3));;
val y : int * (int * int) = (1, (2, 3))
# let z = (1,2),3;;
val z : (int * int) * int = ((1, 2), 3)
# x = y;;
Error: This expression has type int * (int * int)
       but an expression was expected of type int * int * int
# x = z;;
Error: This expression has type (int * int) * int
       but an expression was expected of type int * int * int
```